# AutoMapper with IDataReader to List always returns 0 counts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper, automapper-4

I am using latest version of `AutoMapper` in my application.
I want to convert `DataTable` object to `List` type,
I am using following code
Where reader is of type `DataTable`

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, List<AutoShiftReportConfigDto>>();
var response = Mapper.Map<IDataReader, List<AutoShiftReportConfigDto>>(reader.CreateDataReader());
```

But it returns always 0 Counts, 
My `DataTable` column name are also same as `AutoShiftReportConfigDto`'s property type and name

Comment: Looks like this might be a bug in Automapper (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/835).  Although the github issue states it will be fixed in 4.1, I just put together a quick sample using 4.1 and the mapping returned no rows.

Answer (score 3):

AutoMapper's handling of IDataReader has been pulled out of [core](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) as of version 4. It will eventually land in [Automapper.Data](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Data). If you need this to work, stick with version 3.x.

[Source](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/962)

Comment: Agree, this happened with me as well. Three Cheers Josh!